# string to two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery

i would like to convert this string:

```
'[
  ['Row1 of first array', 'Row2 of first array'],
  ['Row1 of 2nd array', 'Row2 of 2nd array']  
]'
```

Into an array with three arrays of one dimension and two items.

My expected output is an array with 2 elements:

- Array 1
- Array 2

And every array has two elements inside.

Is there any in Jquery to do this conversion?

Comment: Could you post the expected output?

Comment: That's not a valid string as it stands -- you need to use double quotes inside the single quotes.

Comment: if you use `eval()`, this string will be interpreted as array

Comment: Thanks Blazemonger, this answer was exact what i needed.

Comment: @IvanSolntsev No! No `eval`! Bad developer!

Comment: @Blazemonger, haters gonna hate :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a valid string -- you're nesting single quotes inside of single quotes. However, if you convert the string into one using double quotes on the inside:

```
str = '[  ["Row1 of first array", "Row2 of first array"],  ["Row1 of 2nd array", "Row2 of 2nd array"]  ]'
```

then you could simply parse it as a JSON object:

```
arr = $.parseJSON(str); // returns a two-dimensional array
```

This is far, FAR safer than using `eval`, which should only be done when you know EXACTLY what's inside the string, and even then, it's a sign of a lazy developer. When using `parseJSON`, you know that you're getting either an object or an array when you're done -- when using `eval`, anything might happen.

Answer (score -3):

I guess eval will work:

```
var str = eval("[['Row1 of first array', 'Row2 of first array'],['Row1 of 2nd array', 'Row2 of 2nd array']]");

console.log(str);
```

​

Comment: Downvoting this on general principles. Never, ever, ever encourage young coders to use `eval`.